# Find length of decimal places Including trailing zeros from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.9

I have a Pandas dataframe which look like this.

```
Customer ID  Customer Name   Price_Val    
5015            AXN           17.12            
5015            AXN           2.08             
5015            AXN           3.453             
7315            BXN           2.22             
7315            BXN           8.46567             
3283            CXN           88               
3283            CXN           0.4600             
3283            CXN           6.46   
3283            CXN
```

I  want to create  column named **dec_value**. I want dec_value column to have **length of decimal places** from the corresponding **Price_Val** column.

For example I want my dec_value column should look like this.

```
Customer ID  Customer Name   Price_Val  dec_value   
5015            AXN           17.12         2   
5015            AXN           2.08          2   
5015            AXN           3.453         3    
7315            BXN           2.22          2   
7315            BXN           8.4656        4     
3283            CXN           88            0   
3283            CXN           0.4600        4     
3283            CXN           6.46          2
3283            CXN                         0
```

I am using below code to do the above work.

```
i = 0
for value in df1['Price_Val']:
    if value == '':
        df1.loc[i, "dec_value "] = 0
    else:
        colval = value
        k = str(colval)[::-1].find('.')
        if k == -1:
            df1.loc[i,"dec_value"] = 0
        else:
            df1.loc[i,"dec_value"] = str(colval)[::-1].find('.')
    i=i+1
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your column to string, `split` on dot, `rstrip` zeros, and count the characters:

```
df['Price_Val'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split('.')[-1].rstrip('0')))
```

or

```
df['dec_value'] = (df['Price_Val'].fillna('').astype(str)
                                  .str.split('.').str[-1]
                                  .str.rstrip('0').str.len()
                   )
```

output:

```
   Customer ID Customer Name  Price_Val  dec_value
0         5015           AXN   17.12000          2
1         5015           AXN    2.08000          2
2         5015           AXN    3.45300          3
3         7315           BXN    2.22000          2
4         7315           BXN    8.46567          5
5         3283           CXN   88.00000          0
6         3283           CXN    0.46000          2
7         3283           CXN    6.46000          2
8         3283           CXN        NaN          0
```

Alternatively, using a regex:

```
df['dec_value'] = (df['Price_Val'].fillna('').astype(str)
                                  .str.extract('\.(\d*[1-9])', expand=False)
                                  .str.len().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
                  )
```

###### timing of alternatives (90k rows)

```
# apply
50.5 ms ± 913 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# regex
83.9 ms ± 323 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# str pipeline
115 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: with too many `.str` access, it might be better just to `apply` a lambda function.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't know, I'll time it

Comment: @QuangHoang you were right, apply is faster ;) thanks for the tip!

Comment: I need to calculate length of  trailing zeros too. above code doesn't work for below cases. 1.number without decimal **eg: 88 length of decimal places should be 0** case 2. **calculate trailing zeros too  eg 22.200 decimal place length should be 3**.

Comment: Then just remove `.rstrip('0')` that explicitly removed the trailing zeros

Comment: I don't know why values are not matching correctly **eg: for price_val 59389 the decimal place value should be 0 right. I am getting value 5 And for value = 0.05 I am getting decimal places length as 4.** Below code what I used
**df['dec_val']  = df['Price_Val'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split('.')[-1]))**

Comment: What is the original type of the column? If this is float, then what you want is impossible as float don't keep trailing zeros. Zeros might be displayed by pandas but they are **not** in the object

Comment: type of column is string

Comment: Please provide you input as dataframe constructor.